# How can Bootstrap be re-initialized on form elements, specifically checkbox elements, after a .net postback?

Tags: c#, .net, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a screen on a .net driven web application, where a grid is shown. Bootstrap 3.3 is used for display/layout. In the grid, we include checkbox elements for selecting rows of the grid. When the screen is loaded, Bootstrap correctly includes it's  element and hides the actual checkbox input element, and all works as expected. However, if the grid is sorted via a postback after clicking a column header, the checkbox elements all disappear. The screen has to be completed reloaded to get them back.

Seems that Bootstrap isn't reinitializing on the checkbox elements after the postback. How can I trigger Bootstrap to re-init on the form elements in the grid after postback completes?

Answer (score 0):

Here's how we solved this: we couldn't find a way to re-initialize Bootstrap after a .NET async postback. We could, however, re-style the modifications which BS made when the page was loaded, using a two-fold solution:

1.) Employ custom styles on relevant elements using javascript on document load to negate all the Bootstrap mods to elements. Here's the code:

```
function fixBootstrapCheckboxesInFullGrid() {
        $(".full-grid * input[type=checkbox]").css({ 'display': 'inline-block', 'opacity': '1' });
        $(".full-grid * input[type=checkbox] + label").remove();
    }

    /* Adjust checkbox elements on page load (fires after Bootstrap is loaded) */
    $(document).ready(function () {
        fixBootstrapCheckboxesInFullGrid();
    });
```

This block overrides Bootstraps changes (so it must exist *after* the Bootstrap library inclusion). We use JS logic to act directly on elements, to avoid any ordering issues. This style logic is specific to the .full-grid class on the screen being affected, but can be made to be more or less specific to particular elements as required. Also, it's wrapped in a function on purpose, to accommodate the 2nd part below.

2.) Postback tracking: Add pre- and post-postback javascript functionality to the page handler object. This means that any time an asynchronous postback occurs, the pre- and post-postback functions fire at the appropriate times. Here's the logic (also placed at the bottom of the screen), with notes:

```
/* 
ASYNCHRONOUS POSTBACK TRACKING
we use the Application.add_init() to add the beginRequest and endRequest event handlers. 
To add or remove handlers for events raised by the PageRequestManager classes, use the 
add_eventname and remove_eventname methods of those classes.

Note: The pre- and post-postback handler logic came from https://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=256
*/

/* Put any pre-postback operations here */
function beforeAsyncPostBack() {
    //var curtime = new Date();
    //alert('Time before PostBack:   ' + curtime);
}

/* Put any post-postback operations here */
function afterAsyncPostBack() {
    //var curtime = new Date();
    //alert('Time after PostBack:    ' + curtime);
    fixBootstrapCheckboxesInFullGrid()
}

/* Add init function to the PageRequestManager object, which registers the pre- and post-postback handlers. */
Sys.Application.add_init(appl_init);

function appl_init() {
    var pgRegMgr = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
    pgRegMgr.add_beginRequest(BeginHandler);
    pgRegMgr.add_endRequest(EndHandler);
}

/* These fire before/after any postback initialized from this screen */
function BeginHandler() {
    beforeAsyncPostBack();
}

function EndHandler() {
    afterAsyncPostBack();
}
```

So now, when a postback fires, we can do stuff client-side just before the postback executes, and immediately after. In this case, we simply re-apply our style modifications to ensure that the checkbox elements persist in a state we can see and interact with, despite Bootstraps intrusiveness (in this case, anyway).